# react says Error: Invalid hook call when I try to use material makestyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I'm new to react and I'm trying to using makestyles and this is how :

in Header.jsx :

```
import React from "react";
import UseStyles from "./Header_style";
function Header() {
  const classes =UseStyles();
  return (
    <div className={"Main-Header"}>
      <div className={"Header-Logo"}>
        <div className={classes.test}>test</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

and style.js :

```
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/styles';
const UseStyles = makeStyles(theme=>({
    test: {
        backgroundColor: '#BDC3C7',
        color :'red !important',
        widtH : '18%'
    },

    }));
export default UseStyles;
```

but I'm getting folwing error:
×

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
```

*edit:
This is how I'm using Header :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Header from './component/heder/Header.jsx';

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            monsters: [],
            searchField: ''
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Header/>
        );
      }
}


export default App;
```

and another thing, I'm getting following error too :
[image: error]

Comment: 1) how do you use `Header`? 2) [hooks should be named like "useMyHook"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook), so you should use a lower case "u" and make it `useStyles`.

Comment: I tried useStyles . Nothing changes.

Comment: There are 3 reasons that the error gives for an invalid hook call. Have you gone through them and verified that you are not breaking those rules? If so please include the steps you took to verify. And like I mentioned before, please include how you're *using* `Header`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everybody, I've found the solution!

have to use withStyles.

Answer (score 3):

When you place your `Header` component in the return or render of a parent component make sure you use `<Header />` and not {Header}

additionally if that's not the problem you can check this link which is the [official react thread on that error](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html).

Also posting how you render the component that is throwing the error would be very helpful.

Edit* Additionally you don't need to call makeStyles with a function. Since you are not using the theme, you can just call makeStyles with an object like this

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
   test: {
     background: 'white',
     width: '100%'
   }
});
```

**EDIT and additional answers:**

Here's a snippet from [MUI's official page on styles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/):

[image: Difference in makeStyles imports]

The way you import makeStyles:

`import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles`

If you import this way you have to have applied the `@material-ui/styles` module.

If instead in your package.json you use `'@material-ui/core` and haven't installed `@material-ui/styles` you could be getting that error because you don't have the module `@material-ui/styles`.

If you just have `@material-ui/core` you can still import makeStyles without installing the standalone `@material-ui/styles` it is all included in `@material-ui/core`.

Simply import it like this instead:
`import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'`

Comment: @giant In index.js where you are calling ```ReactDOM.render()``` did you ```import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'```?